# Laravel, relationship problems

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

this is my first Laravel project and I have to do a LMS(learning management system).
I have a course table and an user table.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function afficheFormation($id)
    {
        $formation = DB::table('formation')->select('formation.*')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $cours = DB::table('Course')->join('Course_formation', 'course_id', '=', 'Course.id')

            ->select('Course.*')->where('formation_id', $id)->get();


        return view('formation', compact('formation', 'cours'));
    }
```

here is my view code:

```
<tr>
 <td class="align-middle">{{ $cours->name }}</td>
 <td class="align-middle">{{ $cours->level}}</td>    
 <td class="align-middle">{{ $cours->user() }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Course have a foreign key professor_id and I want to display the name of the user which created the course but have some errors

This is my Course model:

```
class Course extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'cours';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'lien', 'type', 'level', 'theme_id', 'prof_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

and this is my user model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'pseudo', 'email', 'password', 'name', 'prenom', 'image'
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
          //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
          return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function cours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Course', 'professor_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls `getProf`? I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: ```public function getProf($idc)
    {
        //$nom = User::where('id', $idc)->get();
        $prof = DB::table('users')->select('users.id')->where('id', $idp)->first();
        return $nom;
    }  ```                                                                                                              getProf was a try of request with join to get the name of the creator, without relationship, so couldn't work I guess.

Comment: You should update your question title to better reflect your question, then. Right now, it reads like you're asking us to fix a problem with code that doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, the title, right, update it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit

Thanks to Abir, I found the way with some changes.

If I understood, Cours::with('user') is a way to call the function user() in the model Cours. Is this right ?

```
public function afficheFormation($id)
    {
        $formation = DB::table('formation')->select('formation.*')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $cours = Cours::with('user')
            ->join('Cours_formation', 'cours_id', '=', 'Cours.id')
            ->select('cours.*')->where('formation_id', $id)->get();

        return view('formation', compact('formation', 'cours'));
    }
```

In the view, we have this code:

```
@if(count($cours)> 0 )
@foreach($cours as $cours)
<tr>
  <td class="align-middle">
  {{ $cours->name }}
  </td>
  <td class="align-middle">
  {{ $cours->niveau}}
  </td>    
  <td class="align-middle">
  {{ $cours->user->name}}
  </td>
</tr> @endforeach
@endif
```

For the Cours model :

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'prof_id', 'id');
    }
```

And finale for the User model :

```
public function cours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cours::class);
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: If you are good with my answer..Mark it as a right answer ..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
$cours = Course::with('cours')
                 ->where('id' , $id)
                 ->get();
```

And In Course Model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User' , 'prof_id');
    }
```

in User Model

```
public function cours() {
          return $this->belongsToMany('App\model\Course', 'prof_id', 'id');
    }
```

Relation Depends on You But it look like this..Hope it will help lil bit

Comment: thanks for the answer but actually not working, it display the name of users. In my exemple I have 3 courses, made by the user named 'test' (id=4 in my table of users) but for the 1st course, it print the first user (id=1), for the 2nd, it print the second user (id=2), ...                                             With the relationship, a user can make many courses, and a course have one creator, so I guess is hasMany belongsTo relationship.